# Basis of vector space $X=Y+Z$ union of bases of $Y$, $Z$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let X be a vector space and Y,Z subspaces of X such that $X=Y+Z$ and $Y\cap Z=\{0\}$.
Is it true that the base of X is the union of the bases of Y and Z?
My proof: let $x\in X$, then there exist $y\in Y,z\in Z$ such that $x=y+z$. If $B_Y$,$B_Z$ the bases of $Y,Z$ respectively, then y and z must be linear combinations of elements of those bases, so $y=\sum \lambda_i b_i$, $z=\sum μ_i β_i$. We know the bases share no elements so for each x there are unique collections $λ_i,μ_i$ and  $b_i \in B_Y$,$β_i \in B_Z$ such that $x=\sum \lambda_i b_i+\sum μ_i β_i$

Comment: Yes, you are right